# Cannot refresh React + Vite application on localhost, when running in preview mode

Tags: reactjs, vite

I react application with routing, using Vite.

I can access the application if I go to the root file (`index.html`) - `http://localhost:4173`, and I can access all pages via React SPA navigation. **But, when I refresh a page which is not the root one, it fails.**

If I try to access a page which is not the root one, for example `http://localhost:4173/account-settings/account`, I get an error:
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxKUF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGJ6s.png)

This is how I preview my application:
`vite preview`.

When I run the application on Development mode, running `vite -c ./vite.config.ts`, everything works, including refresh.

This is my `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta name="description" content="Exlint" />

        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

        <title>...</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>

    <script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>
</html>
```

I expect the application to work also on `preview` mode, as if I get these errors, surely I'd have them on production.

My vite configuration file:

```
import path from 'node:path';
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

const prismaPlugin = () => {
    const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
    const pathName = require.resolve('@prisma/client').replace('@prisma/client/index.js', '');

    return {
        name: 'prisma-vite-plugin',
        config: () => ({
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    '.prisma/client/index-browser': `${pathName}.prisma/client/index-browser.js`,
                },
            },
        }),
    };
};

export default defineConfig(() => ({
    server: {
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
    },
    base: './',
    build: { outDir: './dist' },
    plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths(), prismaPlugin()],
    resolve: { alias: { '@/styles': path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'styles') } },
}));
```

Comment: Try `vite preview --base ./`

Comment: @Konrad Did not help. I had it already configured in my Vite configuration

Answer (score -1):

First you have to build the application and then run the vite preview command.
See the docs here :
https://vitejs.dev/guide/#command-line-interface

Comment: already did. Does not help